# How to solve this linear complementarity problem with NDSolve or other functions? The arguments should be ordered consistently

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, control-systems, fluid-dynamics

[image: eqs]

I want to find a numerical solution of $\omega(t,q)$, where $t\in[0,T]$ and $q\in[0,N]$. $q_t$ is a determinstic w.r.t $t$, other unmentioned parameters can be fullfilled or given by the user.

I met two problems:

1. Can NDSolve handle inequality constraints like the first and second equations? If not, how to deal with it?
2. Mathematicas returns errors: "NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently" and "NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve":

[image]

[image]

My code is:

````
(*Params setting*)
Ν = 100;
Q[t_] := Ν*(1 - Sinh[Χ*(T - t)]/
    Sinh[Χ*T])
κ = 50;
ϕ = 0.001;
λ = N[1/3];
κ = 50;
Χ = 0.002;
Δ = 0.005;
ϵ = 0.005;
γ = Δ + ϵ;
T = 300;
α = 0.001;



(*Solve the equation*)
NDSolve[{(D[ω[t, q], 
       t] - κ*ϕ*(q - Q[t])^2 ω[t, q] + 
      E^-1*λ*ω[t, q + 1])*(ω[t, q] - 
      E^(-κ*γ)*ω[t, q + 1]) == 0,
  ω[T, q] == 
   E^(-κ*(γ + c[Ν - q])*(Ν - q)),
  ω[t, Ν] == E^(-κ*ϕ*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(t\), \(T\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Ν - 
         Q[u])\), \(2\)] \[DifferentialD]u\)\))}, ω, {q, 
  0, Ν}, {t, 0, T}]


```
````

Comment: This equation comes from this paper https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2397805

Comment: In  current versions 12.0-12.2 there are no possibilities to solve this kind of problem with `NDSolve`, I can recommend to use FDM method.

Comment: Also don't use `N` as a parameter, since it is name for the function `N[expr]` gives the numerical value of expr in  Mathematica.